# SELinux Alert Browser not shows nothing

Tags: fedora, selinux

after upgrade SELinux seems to be working, recent alerts in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and `sealert -l *`. But if I open `sealert -b` it doesn't show anything, and all buttons disabled. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You might be running SELinux in "permissive" mode, which means that it logs violations to policies, but doesn't deny any accesses. SELinux has 3 modes, AFAIK: disabled, permissive, and enforcing.

`getenforce` should tell you what more you're in.

You might need to edit `/etc/selinux/config` .

More details: https://docs-old.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/24/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Changing_SELinux_Modes.html